# Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation is running slowly

Tags: c#, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have written this code to find prime numbers, and it works well, but the calculation speeds are incredibly slow.  Am I doing this wrong? I know that I might be really doing this the wrong way, but please help me!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Primenumbers
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        List<int> NoPrime = new List<int>();

        for(int x = 2; x < 10000;x++)
        {
            for(int y = x * 2;y < 10000;y = y + x)
            {

            if(!NoPrime.Contains(y))
                {
                    NoPrime.Add(y);
                }

            }

        }

        for(int z = 2; z < 10000;z++)
        {
            if(!NoPrime.Contains(z))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(z);
            }
        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is off (copy/paste artifact? use spaces, not tabs in SE code blocks ;), and vertical whitespace is inconsistent. You should also consider separating *computing* from *displaying*.

Comment: Never if in fors if you can avoid it.

Comment: If you are unlucky "contains()" could have to loop over all which have previously been added, increasing complexity where you would not have to.

Answer (score 24):

There is some room for improvement in your code, and I will try to explain that in 
several steps. But please note that I am not a C# person, so my review refers only
to the algorithm and performance itself and not to the style or any language
specifics. And most probably I am making a lot of C# errors here.

The following tests were done on a MacBook Pro using
[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/).

To show the performance improvement gained in each step, I have rewritten your code a bit:

- The prime numbers are not printed because printing many lines also takes time. Instead, only the *number* of primes is counted.
- The time for the computation is taken and printed with `StopWatch`.
- Instead of a fixed upper bound (10,000 in your code) the limit is read from
  the command line arguments. I used an upper bound of 50,000.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics; // (for Stopwatch)

namespace Primenumbers
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int maxPrime = int.Parse(args[0]);
            Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int numPrimes = sieve(maxPrime);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} primes in the range 2..{1}, time taken: {2}ms", numPrimes, maxPrime, stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }

        static int sieve(int maxPrime)
        {
            List<int> NoPrime = new List<int>();
            for (int x = 2; x <= maxPrime; x++)
            {
                for (int y = x * 2; y <= maxPrime; y = y + x)
                {
                    if (!NoPrime.Contains(y))
                    {
                        NoPrime.Add(y);
                    }
                }
            }

            int numPrimes = 0;
            for (int z = 2; z <= maxPrime; z++)
            {
                if (!NoPrime.Contains(z))
                {
                    numPrimes++;
                }
            }
            return numPrimes;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
5133 primes in the range 2..50000, time taken: 5744.7922ms
```

**Step 1:** Jeroen Vannevel suggested to use `HashSet` instead of `List`,
and indeed this reduces the runtime considerably:

```
5133 primes in the range 2..50000, time taken: 17.7239ms
```

But an *array of booleans* is much faster because it allows direct access to all elements
without any lookup. Note that this does need *not* much more memory. The number of
primes below a number `N` is approximately `N/log(N)`, so "most" numbers are
not primes. For example, for our upper limit of 50,000 we need an array with
50,000 elements instead of a hash set with 44,867 = 50,000-5,133 elements.

With an array of booleans the `sieve` method would be (thanks to @abligh for suggesting
a better variable name):

```
static int sieve(int maxPrime)
{
    bool[] isComposite = new bool[maxPrime + 1];
    for (int x = 2; x <= maxPrime; x++)
    {
        for (int y = x * 2; y <= maxPrime; y = y + x)
        {
            if (!isComposite[y])
            {
                isComposite[y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Count primes ...
    return numPrimes;
}
```

and now the output is

```
5133 primes in the range 2..50000, time taken: 1.1336ms
```

**Step 2:** If `x` in the `for (int x = ...)` loop has already marked as "not a 
prime" then all the multiples of `x` are also not primes, which means that
the inner `y`-loop needs not to be executed at all. On the other hand, the 
multiples `y` can simply be marked without checking them before:

```
static int sieve(int maxPrime)
{
    bool[] isComposite = new bool[maxPrime + 1];
    for (int x = 2; x <= maxPrime; x++)
    {
        if (!isComposite[x])
        {
            for (int y = x * 2; y <= maxPrime; y = y + x)
            {
                isComposite[y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Count primes ...
    return numPrimes;
}
```

Output:

```
5133 primes in the range 2..50000, time taken: 0.6805ms
```

**Step 3:** If a prime `x` has been found, all lower primes have already been
tested and their multiples marked. Therefore `y` in the inner loop can start
as `x * x` instead of `x * 2`. As a consequence, `x` needs only to run
from 2 to `sqrt(maxPrime)`:

```
static int sieve(int maxPrime)
{
    bool[] isComposite = new bool[maxPrime + 1];
    for (int x = 2; x * x <= maxPrime; x++)
    {
        if (!isComposite[x])
        {
            for (int y = x * x; y <= maxPrime; y = y + x)
            {
                isComposite[y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Count primes ...
    return numPrimes;
}
```

Output:

```
5133 primes in the range 2..50000, time taken: 0.4782ms
```

More improvements are possible, e.g. test only 2 and then every *odd* number,
but I hope this is sufficient for a start.

Finally, here are my measurements for an upper limit of 2,000,000:

- Your method: Don't know, did not wait so long
- Using a hash set: 2601.3797ms
- Using a bool array: 55.2455ms
- After applying "step 2": 19.2888ms
- After applying "step 3": 11.6878ms

Comment: Very interesting answer; I particularly liked the approach of showing the improvements step by step and their effects. It really demonstrates the importance of a good algorithm and the difference a few changes can make.

Comment: To avoid `!notAPrime` perhaps call it `bool[] composite`. Also, what's wrong with `y += x` in the inner loop? (not a C# person either)

Comment: depending on compiler, actually testing !isComposite[y] in the inner loop can make it run (counterintuitively) faster for some obscure reasons (although that's C-related). added bonus: can count primes while marking, no separate sweep needed. (i.e. start with count = n and decrement on each marking).

Answer (score 7):

You're using a `List<T>` and executing `.Contains()` on it. In a list, this will iterate over all the values which ends you up with O(n) time each time the inner loop runs: obviously very slow.

Instead use a `HashSet<T>` which has O(1) lookup.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it, the program now can print the first 2 million prime numbers in under 20 seconds, tyvm!