# Calculate prime numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, primes

This is a program to calculate the largest prime number.  Are there any possible improvements in style/speed/accuracy?

```
public static int? LargestPrime(int max)
{
    if (max < 0)
        return null;
    int largestPrime = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
    {              
        bool? isPrime = IsPrime(i);
        if ((bool)isPrime)
            largestPrime = i;
        if (i % 100000 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(largestPrime.ToString("N0"));
    }
    return largestPrime;
}
private static List<int> listPrimes = new List<int>() { 2, 3 };
private static int listPrimeMax;
private static int listPrimesCount = 100000;
private static bool firstA = true;
private static bool firstB = true;
public static bool? IsPrime(int n)
{    
    if (listPrimes.Count < listPrimesCount)
    {
        // from wiki
        // function is_prime(n : integer)
        // if n ≤ 1
        //     return false
        // else if n ≤ 3
        //     return true
        // else if n mod 2 = 0 or n mod 3 = 0
        //     return false
        // let i ← 5
        // while i×i ≤ n
        //     if n mod i = 0 or n mod(i + 2) = 0
        //         return false
        //     i ← i + 6
        //return true
        if (n < 0)
            return null;
        if (n <= 1)
            return false;
        if (n <= 3)
            return true;
        if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
            return false;
        for (int i = 5; i*i <= n; i += 6)
        {
            if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
                return false;
        }
        if (listPrimes.Count < listPrimesCount)
        {
            listPrimes.Add(n);
            listPrimeMax = n;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(firstA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in listPrimes");
            firstA = false;
        }
        foreach (int i in listPrimes)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
            if (i * i > n)
                break;
        }
        for (int i = listPrimeMax + 2; i*i <= n; i += 2)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        if (listPrimes.Count < 100 * listPrimesCount)
        {
            listPrimes.Add(n);
            listPrimeMax = n;
        }
        else if(firstB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in 100*listPrimes");
            firstB = false;
        }
        return true;
    }           
}
```

Comment: If you want the largest prime in LargestPrime, why don't you start the iteration from max down to zero?

Comment: @HenrikHansen I really meant primes but that is how the question was written

Comment: As negative values have no meaning in the context of primes, you could consider to use uint or maybe ulong instead of int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> public static int? LargestPrime(int max)
> {
>     if (max < 0)
>         return null;
>     int largestPrime = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
>     {              
>         bool? isPrime = IsPrime(i);
>         if ((bool)isPrime)
>             largestPrime = i;
>         if (i % 100000 == 0)
>             Console.WriteLine(largestPrime.ToString("N0"));
>     }
>     return largestPrime;
> }
> ```

- Omitting braces `{}`, although they might be optional, won't do you good in the long run because it makes your code error-prone.
- If an argument of a method isn't correct like `max < 0` you should throw either an `ArgumentException` or better an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
- You are iterating from `0` to `max` to check if the value is a prime, but I wonder what else could the number be? Either it is a prime or it isn't a prime, there is no third way so it doesn't make sense that `IsPrime()` returns a nullable bool.

---

#### bool? IsPrime(int n)

Here you are iterating from `5` to `i*i<n` for each number which is passed to the method.

So let us assume that we pass `max = 10.000.000` (the dots are there for clearity) this

> ```
>     if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
>         return false;
> ```

in the `for` loop in the `IsPrime()` method is executed `16.194.513` times.

By using a sieve you could pretty much speed this thing up like so

```
static int CalculateLargestPrime(int maxPrime)
{
    bool[] isComposite = new bool[maxPrime + 1];
    for (int x = 2; x * x <= maxPrime; x++)
    {
        if (!isComposite[x])
        {
            for (int y = x * x; y <= maxPrime; y = y + x)
            {
                isComposite[y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = maxPrime; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!isComposite[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

taken and adjusted from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62158/29371

Comment: I don't follow.   Will try and test it out.

Comment: @Paparazzi Prime sieve works __basically__ by taking advantage of the fact that when counting sequentially, If you mark off All the multiples of each number you count to (excluding 1 of course), You will be left with only the Primes without marks on them. (you mark the multiples starting with 2x, 3x, 4x, etc, DON'T mark X itself or it won't work) 

If a number already has a mark, it is definitely not prime, but you still have to mark ITS multiples starting at 2x.
Example Below, Parenthesis show Each time a number has been marked 

2 3 (4) 5 ((6)) 7 ((8)) (9) ((10)) 11 ((((12)))) 13 ((14))

Answer (score 3):

**IsPrime**

This method should throw an exception if the number is less then 0. Consequently you would the be able to return a *clean* boolean value. What does the `null` mean anyway - *maybe*?

A number can be either a prime or not or there is an error.  This would make other parts of the code much easier because you wouldn't have to cast it.

Why do you need the `listPrimes` there? This is a very strange design. You add values to it but you never use it, only the `Count` property. For this a simple counter would be more adequate. I don't understand why you need it.

On the other side it should be just `primes`. We don't use type prefixes in C#. Among other variables the `listPrimeMax` is super confusing and misleading. It suggests it's a list but instead it's an `int`.

**firstA firstB**

They don't make any sense and their names don't help to understand their purpose either.

Comment: Really don't use listPrimes?

Comment: Small note - casting would be unnecessary if `IsPrime` would throw exception and in current form this casting [is not working at all](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L2mPKx)

Comment: @Paparazzi - you could try to explain that you are using the list when you've filled it with 100000 prime numbers but not before then. I'd be interested to hear your rationale for that anyway.

Comment: Thx for the DV @Paparazzi but your code is still a mess and you know I'm right. If you cannot accept critique about your code then why do you ask for a review in the first place?

Comment: @Paparazzi do you ever explain yourself or do you think your code is so well written that the answer is obvious? I assure you it's not.

Comment: @RobH You are not aware the occurrence of primes goes down as the number goes up?  Did you test the code?  Do you have something faster?  listPrimesCount is a variable.

Comment: @t3chb0t The use of listPrimes is an essential part of the solution and you totally missed it.

Comment: @Paparazzi yes, I am aware of that and actually yes I have created fast code for this problem when I did some Project Euler problems. What you've done is memoized the algorithm from Wikipedia in an odd way.

Comment: @RobH If you have a better way then posting an answer is an option

Answer (score 3):

> Any improvements in style / speed / accuracy / ..?
>
> ```csharp
> public static int? LargestPrime(int max)
> {
>     if (max < 0)
>         return null;
>     int largestPrime = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
>     {              
>         bool? isPrime = IsPrime(i);
> ```

There's a massive improvement in speed right there. If we end up returning `max - 3` then why do we care whether `max - 2000000` is prime or not? So

```csharp
 public static int? LargestPrime(int max)
 {
     if (max < 2) return null;
     for (int i = max; true; i--)
     {
         if (IsPrime(i)) return i;
     }
 }
```

As to faster ways of testing primality, there must be hundreds of answers covering the topic already. I suggest reading top-voted answers in the [primes](/questions/tagged/primes) tag.

Comment: I really meant all primes but that is the wording of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer ended up with this
With BitArray limited to Int32.Max
But it does up to Int32.Max in 4 minutes

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Int32 maxPrime;
        if (args.Count() == 0)
            maxPrime = Int32.MaxValue-1;
        else
            maxPrime = Int32.Parse(args[0]);
        try
        {
            int lastPrime = GetAllPrimesLessThan(maxPrime);
            Console.WriteLine("Max prime = " + lastPrime.ToString("N0"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    }
    private static int GetAllPrimesLessThan(Int32 maxPrime)
    {           
        if (maxPrime > Int32.MaxValue - 1 || maxPrime < 0)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        int lastPrime = 0;
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var maxSquareRoot = (int)Math.Sqrt(maxPrime);
        var eliminated = new BitArray(maxPrime + 1);
        int count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("GetAllPrimesLessThan starting loop sw " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
        for (int i = 2; i <= maxPrime; ++i)
        {
            if (!eliminated[i])
            {
                count++;
                lastPrime = i;
                if(count % 1000000 == 0 || count <= 1000)
                    Console.WriteLine("Current % 1,000,000 || <= 1000 = " + i.ToString("N0"));
                if (i <= maxSquareRoot)
                    for (int j = i * i; j <= maxPrime && j > 0; j += i)
                        eliminated[j] = true;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("GetAllPrimesLessThan end sw " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
        return lastPrime;
    }
}
```